# SWT CLabel vertical color gradient

Tags: java, colors, swt

Is there a way to draw vertical gradient instead of horizontal color gradient like in
[This tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/CLabelGradientBackground.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the API of [`CLabel`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FCLabel.html), there is a method called

```
setBackground(Color[] colors, int[] percents, boolean vertical)
```

Just use that and set the third parameter to `true`.

Comment: Thanks alot, 
My bad that I didn't look into the declaration

Comment: @becks No worries, you'll know better next time :)